# Search nodes by relation in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to search all the nodes having a particular relation with other node under a root node. Suppose I have one node called A , now i want to find all the nodes having a relation R under node A. So i want to find the child or sub-child of node A having particular relation R.

thanks in advance

UPDATE :

[For example I want to find all the nodes having relation [LIVES_IN] under the node 37 not from the root node(3).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh7bT.png)

Comment: actually i have just started learning cypher. So i do not have any idea how i can achieve it.

Comment: This question is most likely going to be closed as it does not show enough effort and is too broad. Welcome to Stackoverflow, but please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

It is better to start off by learning Cypher by reading the manual http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-query-lang and taking the online course https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-training/introduction-graph-databases/

Once you do this, you'll find that the query is as simple as

```
MATCH (a:SomeLabel {propName:"A"})<-[:PART_OF]-(b:OtherLabel)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c) RETURN c
```

Comment: thanks for your response..
Your query will return all the immediate child of the graph having relation R.   But as i mentioned I needs to find all the nodes of that hierarchy having relation R.

Comment: hey Luanne thanks again.. 
I gave you one example only that is not my original tree I am using in my project. In my case I do not know the intermediate relations ,it  can be n.

Comment: Please update your question with the right set of details. An example dataset and expected query results are always helpful. Can't keep guessing :-)